# template <class T> T type can not convert size_t

Tags: python, c++, templates, pyobject

I use template but I get error I dont know why. there is no PyInt_FromInt function.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void PyGiveArguments(PyObject* Obj,T arg)
{
    Obj = PyTuple_New(PyTuple_GET_SIZE(Obj)+1);
    if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(Obj, PyTuple_GET_SIZE(Obj) + 1, PyString_FromString(arg.c_str()));
        return;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
    {
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(Obj, PyTuple_GET_SIZE(Obj) + 1, PyLong_FromSize_t(arg));
        return;
    }
}
```

it says (else if T,int block ) "argument cannot be converted from 'T' to 'size_t'";

I tried type convert but didnt help. I use pointer also didnt help

Comment: `if` is a runtime mechanism. If you use it, both branches must still be valid code from compile time perspective. In C++17 you can use `if constexpr`, before that it's going to be more involved.

Comment: Okay, the duplicates are more about classes, so they don't mention it, but overloading is also an option and should be preferred where `if constexpr` won't work and overloads are possible.